# Can I run a php file from the root folder of all domains?

Tags: server, directadmin

I have a user in a server that has many sites under many domains. there's a folder "domains" and then the domains, and under each one there's public_html folder where the site goes and I can access it by using the domain.

I use Direct Admin panel in order to handle everything.

I want to run a PHP file that will run a script for all domains, I can upload the file in the "domains" folder, but how can I access it to run it?